# Why is SSH permission denied unless sshd is in debug mode

Tags: ssh, centos, centos-6, sshd

I have problems ssh to my own box (both remotely or locally) with the message

> Permission denied, please try again.

Then I stop the sshd service with `/etc/init.d/sshd stop` and start sshd in debug mode `/usr/sbin/sshd -d`.
I can connect this time, both remotely or locally works.

I cannot figure out what's the difference between these two situations.
Any hints will be highly appreciated.
Thank you and best regards!

Comment: The title of your post needs to be a question. How about "Why is SSH permission denied unless sshd is in debug mode?"

Comment: which disto are you using, and copy how you try your login `ssh ...`</br> If you are trying to log in ar root@server it won't let you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a password set for your user? If not, you may have to either set a password or use key-based ssh authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do have a password set for my account. :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Disabling SELinux solved it for me.

You can try to temporary disable SELinux:

```
echo 0 >/selinux/enforce
```

or permanent:

```
#/etc/selinux/config
SELINUX=disabled
```

Comment: Ehm, this is NOT something you want to do with the possible exception as to debugging the problem. It is akin to "My lock is rusty. Lets solve it by jamming the front door open".